# Windows Phone 7/Silverlight: How to do navigation?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Silverlight wp7 app. I'm not sure exactly how to do navigation.

I have several `PhoneApplicationPage` classes, which contain several `UserControl`s. It looks like I can use `NavigationService` to navigate from the `PhoneApplicationPage` classes, but not the `UserControl` classes. Is that preferable? Is the general pattern not to navigate directly from a `UserControl`, but to handle it from a `PhoneApplicationPage`?

Currently, I have a collection of content separated into sections. Each section has its own `PivotItem` in a `PivotControl`. The content for each section is in a `ListBox`. I wrapped the `ListBox` in a `UserControl` to provide a little more functionality/managing the content. However, it looks like I can't navigate directly from this class.

I could remove the wrapper and just put the functionality in the pivot page directly. But what if I want to repeat the content list elsewhere in my app?

Alternatively, I pass `NavigationService` to the `UserControl` when it's constructed by the `PhoneApplicationPage`.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, it would be simple: You'd call the static method on `NavigationService` to get your answer: `NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this)`.

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be available in WP7.

Instead, I came up with this hack... It is ugly as sin... hopefully there is something better.  Possibly, at least, you can come up with something a bit more pretty.  At least do some null checking...

```
var service = ((Application.Current as App).RootFrame.Content as Page).NavigationService;
```

Answer (score 2):

In WP7, the RootVisual is always a `PhoneApplicationFrame`, and since `NavigationService` and `Frame` (or `PhoneApplicationFrame`) share almost all their methods/properties (intentionally), you can do this:

```
(Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(...whatever...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom UserControl for this:

```
public class UserControlWithNavigation :UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler NavigateToPageEvent;

    public void NavigateToPage(Uri uri)
    {             
        var e = new NavigationEventArgs(null, uri);
        if (NavigateToPageEvent != null)
            NavigateToPageEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

XAML use of the custom `UserControl` class:

```
<common:UserControlWithNavigation    
  xmlns:common="clr-namespace:NameSpace;assembly=AssemblyName"
```

and in my Page

```
 MyUserControl.NavigateToPageEvent += (s, e) =>
 {
      NavigationService.Navigate(((NavigationEventArgs)e).Uri);
 };
```

As you see, you have to give your `UserControl` a name (`MyUserControl` in above example)

Answer (score 0):

I did a sample of navigating using MVVM Light at http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2010/10/10/another-wp7-navigation-approach-with-mvvm.html. It could use some refactoring and some prefer to put some of the navigation helper functions in another class other than a base page. That's easy enough to do though and it might give some ideas.